# ValueError: ('Error when checking model target: expected no data, but got

Tags: tensorflow, valueerror, voxel

I am doing 3D-VAE with voxel(32,32,32). It seems to me that there is no problem, but I keep getting an error. I tried everything in TensorFlow versions 2.0, 2.1, and 2.2.

This is VAE model.

```
def get_model():
    enc_in = Input(shape = input_shape)

    enc_conv1 = BatchNormalization()(
        Conv3D(
            filters = 8,
            kernel_size = (3, 3, 3),
            strides = (1, 1, 1),
            padding = 'valid',
            kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal',
            activation = 'elu',
            data_format = 'channels_first')(enc_in))
    enc_conv2 = BatchNormalization()(
        Conv3D(
            filters = 16,
            kernel_size = (3, 3, 3),
            strides = (2, 2, 2),
            padding = 'same',
            kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal',
            activation = 'elu',
            data_format = 'channels_first')(enc_conv1))
    enc_conv3 = BatchNormalization()(
        Conv3D(
            filters = 32,
            kernel_size = (3, 3, 3),
            strides = (1, 1, 1),
            padding = 'valid',
            kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal',
            activation = 'elu',
            data_format = 'channels_first')(enc_conv2))
    enc_conv4 = BatchNormalization()(
        Conv3D(
            filters = 64,
            kernel_size = (3, 3, 3),
            strides = (2, 2, 2),
            padding = 'same',
            kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal',
            activation = 'elu',
            data_format = 'channels_first')(enc_conv3))

    enc_fc1 = BatchNormalization()(
        Dense(
            units = 343,
            kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal',
            activation = 'elu')(Flatten()(enc_conv4)))
    mu = BatchNormalization()(
        Dense(
            units = z_dim,
            kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal',
            activation = None)(enc_fc1))
    sigma = BatchNormalization()(
        Dense(
            units = z_dim,
            kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal',
            activation = None)(enc_fc1))
    z = Lambda(
        sampling,
        output_shape = (z_dim, ))([mu, sigma])

    encoder = Model(enc_in, [mu, sigma, z])

    dec_in = Input(shape = (z_dim, ))

    dec_fc1 = BatchNormalization()(
        Dense(
            units = 343,
            kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal',
            activation = 'elu')(dec_in))
    dec_unflatten = Reshape(
        target_shape = (1,7,7,7))(dec_fc1)

    dec_conv1 = BatchNormalization()(
        Conv3DTranspose(
            filters = 64,
            kernel_size = (3, 3, 3),
            strides = (1, 1, 1),
            padding = 'same',
            kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal',
            activation = 'elu',
            data_format = 'channels_first')(dec_unflatten))
    dec_conv2 = BatchNormalization()(
        Conv3DTranspose(
            filters = 32,
            kernel_size = (3, 3, 3),
            strides = (2, 2, 2),
            padding = 'valid',
            kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal',
            activation = 'elu',
            data_format = 'channels_first')(dec_conv1))
    dec_conv3 = BatchNormalization()(
        Conv3DTranspose(
            filters = 16,
            kernel_size = (3, 3, 3),
            strides = (1, 1, 1),
            padding = 'same',
            kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal',
            activation = 'elu',
            data_format = 'channels_first')(dec_conv2))
    dec_conv4 = BatchNormalization()(
        Conv3DTranspose(
            filters = 8,
            kernel_size = (4, 4, 4),
            strides = (2, 2, 2),
            padding = 'valid',
            kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal',
            activation = 'elu',
            data_format = 'channels_first')(dec_conv3))
    dec_conv5 = BatchNormalization(
        beta_regularizer = l2(0.001),
        gamma_regularizer = l2(0.001))(
        Conv3DTranspose(
            filters = 1,
            kernel_size = (3, 3, 3),
            strides = (1, 1, 1),
            padding = 'same',
            kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal',
            data_format = 'channels_first')(dec_conv4))

    decoder = Model(dec_in, dec_conv5)

    dec_conv5 = decoder(encoder(enc_in)[2])

    vae = Model(enc_in, dec_conv5)

    return {'inputs': enc_in, 
            'outputs': dec_conv5,
            'mu': mu,
            'sigma': sigma,
            'z': z,
            'encoder': encoder,
            'decoder': decoder,
            'vae': vae}

def weighted_binary_crossentropy(target, output):
    loss = -(98.0 * target * K.log(output) + 2.0 * (1.0 - target) * K.log(1.0 - output)) / 100.0
    return loss
```

and This is loss and fit

```
voxel_loss = K.cast(K.mean(weighted_binary_crossentropy(inputs, K.clip(sigmoid(outputs), 1e-7, 1.0 - 1e-7))), 'float32') # + kl_div
vae.add_loss(voxel_loss)

sgd = SGD(lr = learning_rate_1,  momentum = momentum, nesterov = True)

vae.compile(optimizer = sgd, metrics = ['accuracy'])
# vae.compile(optimizer = sgd, loss = vae_loss(inputs, sigmoid(outputs)), metrics = ['accuracy'])


vae.fit(
        x_train,x_train,
        epochs = epoch_num,
        batch_size = batch_size,
        validation_data = (x_test, x_test),
        callbacks = [LearningRateScheduler(learning_rate_scheduler)]
    )
```

and error is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-b1e0bf03e31b> in <module>
     30         batch_size = batch_size,
     31         validation_data = (x_test, x_test),
---> 32         callbacks = [LearningRateScheduler(learning_rate_scheduler)]
     33     )
     34 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf19/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1261         steps_name='steps_per_epoch',
   1262         steps=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1263         validation_split=validation_split)
   1264 
   1265     # Prepare validation data.

~/anaconda3/envs/tf19/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split)
    905           feed_output_shapes,
    906           check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 907           exception_prefix='target')
    908 
    909       # Generate sample-wise weight values given the `sample_weight` and

~/anaconda3/envs/tf19/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    114     if data is not None and hasattr(data, '__len__') and len(data):
    115       raise ValueError('Error when checking model ' + exception_prefix + ': '
--> 116                        'expected no data, but got:', data)
    117     return []
    118   if data is None:

ValueError: ('Error when checking model target: expected no data, but got:', array([[[[[-1., -1., -1., ..., -1., -1., -1.],
          [-1., -1., -1., ..., -1., -1., -1.],
          [-1., -1., -1., ..., -1., -1., -1.],
          ...,
          [-1., -1., -1., ..., -1., -1., -1.],
          [-1., -1., -1., ..., -1., -1., -1.],
          [-1., -1., -1., ..., -1., -1., -1.]],
```

I saw that the meaning of target is output. But my output is reconstructed data, I can't understand why it is expected no data. Please help

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the full traceback in your post.

Comment: @ewong I I included the full trackback. thank you!